# Requesting airdrop of 1 SOL on the devnet

Tags: wallet, solana, airdrop

I have properly setup a Solana wallet on the devnet, using these commands:

```
curl https://release.solana.com/v1.8.6/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs

C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.8.6

solana-keygen new --outfile C:/Users/Usermame/.config/solana/devnet.json

solana config set --keypair C:/Users/Usermame/.config/solana/devnet.json

solana config get
```

And it successfully created a Solana wallet. However, when I ran:

```
solana airdrop 1
```

It said:

```
Requesting airdrop of 1 SOL
Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds
```

I have successfully airdropped 1 SOL to a Solana wallet on a devnet before, I don't know why this is not working.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the devnet runs out of the faucets due to some dev asking for more than required faucets.

Have ran into same problem many times now.

One such instance was highlighted by core-contributor on the community group.

[image: faucet-outage]

**SOLUTION**:
Either you can wait for validators to mint new faucets

OR

Ask for faucet in discord. That should do.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, sometimes the devnet is out; however, that is also just a potential message you get when the devnet(or any net) is down as well.  You can ask in the server; otherwise, you can try other networks like the test network or deploying locally in the meantime.